# How to delete all AWS Transcribe Jobs at once through CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-transcribe

I am trying to delete all of my AWS Transcribe jobs at the same time. I know I can go through and delete them one by one through the console, and I can also delete them all through the CLI through the following command:

```
$ aws transcribe delete-transcription-job --transcription-job-name YOUR_JOB_NAME
```

The issue with this is that I have to do this for each individual job! I am dealing with them on a mass scale (about 1000 jobs), and I don't want to have to go in and delete each one manually (even with a Automator set up on my Mac, this is not efficient'. Is there anyway to just delete every Transcribe job instead of putting the specific job name in?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like it. The closest option is to write a script that lists out all the jobs with `list-transcription-jobs` and  then loops through deleting them:

```sh
for jobName in $(aws transcribe list-transcription-jobs --query '[TranscriptionJobSummaries[*].TranscriptionJobName]' --output text);
  do aws transcribe delete-transcription-job --transcription-job-name $jobName;
done
```

Note there is sometimes a limit to the number of records AWS CLI will return in one call. You may have to run this multiple times or write the script to use the `--next-token` argument to page through the entire list of jobs.

See: [delete-transcription-job — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/transcribe/delete-transcription-job.html)

Comment: Thanks for this. You can also increase the number of job results if you set, `aws transcribe list-transcription-jobs --max-results 100` (100 is the current maximum you can retrieve)